# Android Development - isChecked Checkbox using simple_list_item_multiple_choice and CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE

Tags: android, checkboxlist, ischecked

I am using simple_list_item_multiple_choice with list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); to create a list of check boxes populated from a database query.  I am then using onListItemClick to handle the clicking of the list, again that is working fine.  What I can find no way of doing (after 5 days) is writing an if statement based on whether or not the check box attached to the list item is checked.  What I need is the equivalent of the example below which works perfectly for a check box where I can use the  android:onClick element to fire the method below.

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View v) {
        // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

This is critical to my app so any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Below is the simpleCusrorAdapter is am using:

```
 Cursor cursor3 = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, symname FROM tblsymptoms WHERE _id IN ("+sympresult+") ", null);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                cursor3, 
                new String[] {"symname","_id"}, 
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView list=getListView();
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the problem after finding this very useful [blog item](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/listactivity-with-checkbox-using.html)

I changed my onListItemClick to the following and it works like a dream:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {


      CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView)view;
      check.setChecked(!check.isChecked());
      boolean click = !check.isChecked();
      check.setChecked(click);
      if (click) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } 
}
```

Comment: Why is check.setChecked() called twice ? '   check.setChecked(!check.isChecked());
      boolean click = !check.isChecked();
      check.setChecked(click);'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, each row in your list has a checkbox.  When an item in the list is selected you want to be able to tell if the corresponding checkbox is checked?

Try to use the setTag(...) method on each list item View object.  Then when onListItemClick() method is called you can call getTag(...) on the view (which will return your checkbox).  I assume that you are using a custom Adapter to populate the list.  While populating you want to call:

```
   setTag( CHECKBOX_KEY, checkbox );
```

For example:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.getTag( CHECKBOX_KEY );

    boolean isChecked = false;

    if( null != cb ) {
        isChecked = cb.isChecked();
    }

    // .. do whatever you have to here...    

}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks like exactly what I need but I do not know how to use the first part of your answer - setTag( CHECKBOX_KEY, checkbox).  I have added my SimpleCursorAdapter to my original question, I just need help with the customer adapter bit and I will be there I hope.  Many thanks in advance